# UITableView send selection to email address

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sendmail

I've got an list with objects in a TableView. The list with objects is being loaded from an external .plist on a server. Now I'd like to get that when the cells in the TableView are tapped they become another colour (green) and when finished tapping cells you can press a button which sends the tapped cells(the names of the objects) to an email address or a server, so the owner of the app can see which objects were selected.

Can anyone help me (or point me in the right direction) on how to make this?

My code for the TableView: (view controller.m)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Stuff.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Stuff *s = [[Stuff alloc] init];

    [s getStuff];

    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:s.stuff];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.items count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *id = @"plistdata";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:id  forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:id];
}

cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

@end
```

If more of my code is required please let me know

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about putting up a UIActivityController with [just] the email option?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you read up on UITableView on the apple site.

However if you're looking to trigger something when a cell is tapped/selected then perhaps you should consider

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to keep track of the cells that have been tapped. I'd also make sure that you have multi selection enabled on your table view.

Perhaps read this http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-row-selection-and-editing-in.html

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. Can you also help me with how I can send the tapped selections to an email address or a server?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array with same size of email list you have loaded previously which is same number of rows in the table view and fill this array with boolean objects that is false

and in CellForRowAtIndexPath get the boolean Object from that array with indexPath.row and check its values  True is Green , False is default color

then Set the boolean value to true that have same index as selected cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath then on UITableView  call loadData method to refresh the interface